# Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait

how can I use WebDriverWait(driver, 10) for this code?
because I cant not extract data for more than one page

```
    ff=['https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2017-2018/tottenham-manchester-city-ddkDE7Ld/#over-under;2','https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2017-2018/burnley-bournemouth-xSUUEVHO/#over-under;2']
    webD=wb.Chrome(r'C:\Users\PERSONL\Downloads\chromedriver_win32 (1)\chromedriver.exe')
    k=len(ff)
    for i in range(k):
        webD.get(ff[i])
        c03= webD.find_elements_by_class_name('bt-2')
        c05=c03.find_elements_by_class_name('table-container')
        c04=c03.find_elements_by_tag_name('strong')
        kk.append(c04)

        
    fla=kk[0]

    print(fla)
    for i in fla:
        m=i.text
        num.append(m)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one webelement having class 'bt-2', so it should be `webD.find_element_by_class_name` (without the "s" in element**s**). This line should anyway be rewritten as

```
c03 = WebDriverWait(webD, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'bt-2')))
```

Also you can iterate the `ff` list of urls like this, rather than using range/indexes (it's more pythonic):

```
num=[]
for url in ff:
    driver.get(url)
    c03 = WebDriverWait(webD, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'bt-2')))
    c05 = c03.find_elements_by_class_name('table-container')
    c04 = c03.find_elements_by_tag_name('strong')
    for i in c04:
        print(i.text)
        num.append(i.text)
```

Comment: Message: The element reference of is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed

Comment: Btw, just to be sure...as your webdriver instance is called "webD", it should be `WebDriverWait(webD, 10)`. Please confirm you have replaced all "driver" references to "webD".

Comment: iam using more than one link and this message appear I thought WebDriverWait can solve it is there any way sir?

Comment: can you please help me

Comment: I see the problem now. Same issue but for the second loop. I have removed what I believe are some redundant lines in your code. See update.